# How can I print underlined text in C/C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm coding an application, and want to print underlined text. What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using a "translated" code from C#, normally it works great in C# but does not in C++. After I fixed the errors, the code simply does not work. It shows some characters that normaly won't. This is what it prints instead (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAPPQ.png)

Here's the code I used

```
auto DllHandler = GetStdHandle(-11);
unsigned int Mode;
GetConsoleMode(DllHandler,PDWORD(Mode));
Mode |= 4;
SetConsoleMode(DllHandler,DWORD(Mode));
cout << "\x1b[5mUnderlined \x1b[0mtext" << endl;
```

And here's the original (C#) code:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out uint lpMode);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, uint dwMode);
        var DllHandler = Kernel32.GetStdHandle(-11);
        uint Mode;
        GetConsoleMode(DllHandler,out Mode);
        Mode |= 4;
        SetConsoleMode(DllHandler, Mode);
        Console.Write("\x1b[5mUnderlined \x1b[0mText");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That mostly depends on your terminal font settings and how you can control these.

Comment: Does Windows console really support ANSI escape sequences? It seems strange that it works in C#. The `Console` object might interpret these to do actual API calls to change console mode, I suppose.

Comment: use `\x1b[4m` instead `\x1b[5m`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237666/adding-text-decorations-to-console-output/43078669#43078669

Comment: @Ruslan - yes, really support. dont check from which version, but support with [*ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) - look for [*Console Virtual Terminal Sequences*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)

Comment: for text formating used *ESC [ <n> m* code and *4 Underline Adds underline* - so need use `\x1b[4m`

Comment: anyway this work only for win 10 and you not *Checking whether SetConsoleMode returns 0 and GetLastError returns STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER is the current mechanism to determine when running on a down-level system. An application receiving STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER with one of the newer console mode flags in the bit field*

Comment: RbMm Oops that was my mistake, but 4m still won't fix it... I assume the problem is with PDWORD/DWORD, in .NET languages I use unsigned 16 bit integer and works just fine.

Comment: your problem that you not check results of functions call. not check error code. what is your windows version also ?

Comment: `GetConsoleMode(DllHandler,PDWORD(Mode));` of course also error. must be `GetConsoleMode(DllHandler, &Mode);` and `ULONG Mode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @RbMm said, use `ULONG` type can compile successfully and achieve the desired results.

But the real cause of the error is the error of pointer transmission.
If you want to use `unsigned int`, the first step is to apply for pointers and allocate memory for pointers, and then force type conversion in `GetConsoleMode`.

```
    auto DllHandler = GetStdHandle(-11);
    unsigned int *Mode = new unsigned int;
    GetConsoleMode(DllHandler, PDWORD(Mode));
    *Mode = *Mode | 4;
    SetConsoleMode(DllHandler, DWORD(*Mode));
    cout << "\x1b[4mUnderlined \x1b[4mtext" << endl;

    delete Mode;
```